# Twitter API OAuth: Requesting a user token

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

My app is using the [Twitter API PHP wrapper](https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php) to allow users to access Twitter.

I'm stuck on the first step of authorisation: requesting a token on behalf of a user. I understand that I need to supply an encoded callback URL. I do that, and I've checked it matches the one defined in my Twitter app settings.

However the message I get back is "Sorry, that page does not exist".

Here is my code, grateful any help:

```
require_once( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '../lib/TwitterAPIExchange.php');
$settings = array(
    'oauth_access_token' => $twitter_oauth_access_token,
    'oauth_access_token_secret' => $twitter_oauth_access_token_secret,
    'consumer_key' => $twitter_consumer_key,
    'consumer_secret' => $twitter_consumer_secret
);

$callback_url = urlencode(site_url() . '/settings');

$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/oauth/request_token.json';
// $url = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token.json';
$postfields = array(
    'oauth_callback' => $callback_url
);

$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$results = $twitter->buildOauth($url, 'POST')
             ->setPostfields($postfields)
             ->performRequest();
$response = json_decode($results, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong url to request the token. It should be:

https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token

Note: without the `.json` extension.

Comment: Actually the TwitterAPIExchange library requires all endpoints are suffixed with '.json'. Please read the TwitterAPIExchange documentation linked to in the original question.